# Counting occurrences of a string in a string

Tags: php, string

My question is the following:

Is there a string function that returns a count of occurrences, like `substr_count()`, but with a limiting option? I want to count the occurrences of 'a' in a string, but before the first newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/substr) to grab everything before the newline character, and then use [`substr_count()`](http://php.net/substr_count) to get the number of occurrences:

```
$text = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "\n"));
echo substr_count($text, $needle);
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/56721)

Comment: This is a faster solution than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). It returns the count of matches.  With a regex you can easily stop on a newline.

(Note: Amal's substr solution is faster than using a regular expression.)